# How can I get a value from an observer inside another?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

How do I make this line return a value in the subscribe ? It is returning an observable instead:

```
let test = undefined;
of(test, this.myService.whatever(var1, var2))
    .pipe(
        first(n=>!!n) 
    ).subscribe(result=>console.log(result)); // returns Observable, should return value.
```

myservice.whatever returns an observable. I want to make it resolve inside pipe. Something like this:

```
let test = undefined;
of(test, this.myService.whatever(var1, var2))
    .pipe(
        first(n=>!!n),
        getValueFromObserver() // if it's an observer get the value
    ).subscribe(result=>console.log(result));
```

Is this possible ? 
What I'm trying to do is check inside the observer's sequence if a local variable has a value and if it doesn't, then get the value from the backend. I want to make this because the real code is far more complex and the result of this observable will be forkJoined with other observers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haven't fully tested but theoretically, you can check `instanceof`

```
let test = undefined;
of(test, this.myService.whatever(var1, var2))
    .pipe(
        first(n => !!n),
        switchMap(value => value instanceof Observable ? value : of(value))
    ).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```